# Checking packages state in Synaptic

Tags: package-management, checkinstall

I have recently installed some packages which are necessary for building executables:

> python-central \
>
> texlive-latex-base \
>
> texlive-latex-extra \
>
> texlive-latex-recommended \
>
> texlive-fonts-extra \
>
> texlive-fonts-recommended \

Using Synaptic package manager on Debian distro. Didn't consider that the final size of the packages after extraction would wipe all free space on the root partition.

Got the error while installation progress and it was interrupted. But after expanding the partition and launching Synaptic no error was displayed. And every package listed above is marked as alreary installed.

So I guess that some of dependencies were not installed correclty. How can I perform the revision of recently installed packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on dpkg-based distributions,

List of Packages with status by date,

`grep install /var/log/dpkg.log`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Found packages with `not-installed` status: `2018-04-29 23:00:56 status not-installed texlive-latex-extra-doc:all <нет>`          `2018-04-29 23:05:12 status not-installed texlive-pstricks-doc:all <нет>`